# iOS app iPhone 5s iOS 7 app display height

Tags: ios

I have developed an app for iOS 8 on iPhone 5s using storyboard layout.

But I found that when the system is changed to iOS 7 Display Height Is changed into Does not fit the screen size.
iPhone 4s screen size show app interface.

Comment: I don't have a clue what your question is or what your issue you is. Voting to close as unclear what you are asking us.

Comment: Can please attach snap if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean ran the app using iPhone5S?
By saying "use storyboard layout" did you mean using Autolayout?
Probably you are not using Autolayout, or you didn't set the constraints working quiet well.

Here is the reference you may find useful. Copyright reserved by apple.
Section “Adaptivity and Layout” in 《IOS Human Interface Guideline》(You can download from iBook).

Also Autolayout Reference.[Auto layout Reference provide by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

you will find the edit selection at the button of Storyboard editing page.(I don't have the authority to publish picture)

Hope that this may help.

Comment: Please don't use text language to answer questions. Also what do you mean by `Do you mean you developed the app using iPhone5S?`? You develop **for** or **on** an iPhone 5s you don't. Develop using, you use xcode to develop. And was there a link meant to be included in your answer as the second part doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry~Umm. As I said I am not yet have the authority to post a picture. For the language problem I will fix it. Thx~

Comment: I was talking more about `Copyright reserved by apple. Section “Adaptivity and Layout” in 《IOS Human Interface Guideline》(You can download from iBook).` What's with the copyright?